# How can I assign the Euro or the Pound symbol to a variable?

Tags: java

I need to assign the Euro or the Pound symbol to a variable. How can i do this?

```
String euro = "";// What i have to write here??
System.out.println(euro);// I need to print euro symbol
```

Comment: You can put the symbol itself into the string

Answer (score 37):

```
public class ExampleEuroPound {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String euro = "\u20ac";
        String pound = "\u00a3";

        System.out.println("pound = " + pound);
        System.out.println("euro = " + euro);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

If you can't type it then you could use the unicode value for euro:

```
String euro = "\u20AC";
System.out.println(euro);
```

If you're doing this however, best practice is to comment it and / or save it as a constant field for clarity (unexplained unicode literals in code are just plain confusing!):

```
public static final String POUND = "\u00A3";
public static final String EURO = "\u20AC";
```

Comment: That helped in android too, +1 for it

Answer (score 4):

```
public final static char EURO = '\u20ac';
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd wonder if you'd be better off using the currency formatter for numbers in the `java.text` package.  IF there's ever a chance that you'd want to use something other than euro, based on locale, this would be a better choice.

You might also think about a Money class.  I think you need a better abstraction than mere Strings or doubles for programs that involve cash.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

- Type or copy/paste the Euro/Pound symbol into your source code. This requires the editor/IDE to support these characters (typically not a problem) and to use an encoding that does (potentially a problem), and for the compiler to use the same encoding (potentially a problem). Overall, this is risky since it can break whenever something in the development or build environment changes.
- Use a [unicode escape sequence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Syntax/Unicode_Escape_Sequences) in the source code: `\u20AC` is the Euro sign, `\u00A3` the Pound sign.

Answer (score 2):

What would be the point of doing

```
String euro = "€";
```

Comment: Since this was downvoted for no reason, I add that the source file is in ISO-8859-15 or Unicode

Answer (score 2):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
String euro = "\u20AC";
```

Answer (score 1):

A full list of Unicode currency symbols is available as [a pdf here.](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf)